# How to get the max value out of list

Tags: python

I am looking to get the highest "high" out of the dict below.

**Response** =

```
 [  
       {  
          'timestamp':'2019-04-13T04:12:00.000Z',
          'symbol':'XBTUSD',
          'open':5065,
          'high':5067,
          'low':5065.5,
          'close':5066.5,
          'trades':13,
          'volume':10002,
          'vwap':5066.8829,
          'lastSize':2,
          'turnover':197408849,
          'homeNotional':1.9740884899999998,
          'foreignNotional':10002
       },
       {  
          'timestamp':'2019-04-13T04:11:00.000Z',
          'symbol':'XBTUSD',
          'open':5065,
          'high':5065,
          'low':5065,
          'close':5065,
          'trades':0,
          'volume':0,
          'vwap':None,
          'lastSize':None,
          'turnover':0,
          'homeNotional':0,
          'foreignNotional':0
       },
       {  
          'timestamp':'2019-04-13T04:10:00.000Z',
          'symbol':'XBTUSD',
          'open':5065,
          'high':5065,
          'low':5065,
          'close':5065,
          'trades':2,
          'volume':2000,
          'vwap':5065,
          'lastSize':397,
          'turnover':39486000,
          'homeNotional':0.39486,
          'foreignNotional':2000
       }
    ]
```

Then to get all 'high' printed:

```
for h in response:
   print (h['high'])
```

Which prints:

**5067
5065
5065**

Then the question arises of how do I get the max value out of the list of numbers? It would be "5067" in this case. I have tried to use the max method, but to no avail. `(max(h['high']))` does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Use `itemgetter` and the `key` parameter:

```
from operator import itemgetter

max(h, key=itemgetter('high'))
```

Answer (score 2):

[max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)(iterable, *[, key, default]) - Return the largest item in an iterable or the largest of two or more arguments.

```
b=max(a, key=lambda x:x['high'])
print(b['high'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to obtain all the values from the `high` key then use the `max()` function to get the maximum

```
maximum = max([h['high'] for h in response])
print(maximum)
```

> 5067