# Compare the values between keys of dictionaries in a list and return the one with maximum value and next key on the basis of this value

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list that contains a dictionary as its elements. I want to compare the value of a particular key here 'ce_fraction'
with the value of the same keys in other dictionary and return the value of key 'ce_symbol' of which the value of 'ce_fraction' is:
 maximum. For example from the following I need to return 'ce_symbol': 'S:1', as its corresponding value for 'ce_fraction', is maximum between all dictionaries in the list.

```
d1 = [{'ce_symbol': 'S:1',
   'ce_fraction': 0.9826993502161626,
   'csm': 0.0,
   'permutation': [0]},
  {'ce_symbol': 'ST:7',
   'ce_fraction': 0.01729545180302663,
   'csm': 6.419666329644907,
   'permutation': [3, 1, 4, 6, 0, 5, 2]},
  {'ce_symbol': 'TL:3',
   'ce_fraction': 5.112772362143661e-06,
   'csm': 5.01422215914756,
   'permutation': [0, 1, 2]},
  {'ce_symbol': 'TS:3',
   'ce_fraction': 6.631085890198608e-08,
   'csm': 7.49194295399119,
   'permutation': [0, 2, 1]},
  {'ce_symbol': 'TY:3',
   'ce_fraction': 1.8897589832589626e-08,
   'csm': 7.720504649029379,
   'permutation': [0, 1, 2]}]
```

I have many such lists and need to do for the one having more than one dictionary as elements in the list.
I can print the values and keys in a new list but I need to compare them. Could anyone please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

```
for i in range(len(d1)):
        ce_frac = []
        symbol = []
        if len(d1[i]) >1:
            for j in range(len(d1[i])):
                    ce_frac.append(d1[j]['ce_fraction'])
                    symbol.append(d1[j]['ce_symbol'])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the max value out of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55661957/how-to-get-the-max-value-out-of-list)

Comment: There you only need the maximum value, but here I need next key on the basis of this maximum value.

Comment: b=max(d1, key=lambda x:x['ce_fraction'])
print(b['ce_symbol'])   first find the maximum and specify the key you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I take your full example as an input, I would start by making a list of symbol and fractions.

```
ce_frac = []
symbol = []
for d in d1:
    for item in d:
        ce_frac.append(item['ce_fraction'])
        symbol.append(item['ce_symbol'])
```

Then I find the maximum value in ce_frac list and find it's index, and the answer is the symbol appearing at that index in symbol list

```
#Get Maximum value of ce_fraction and find it's index
max_frac = max(ce_frac)
max_idx = ce_frac.index(max_frac)
#It's symbol will be present at the same index in symbol
print(symbol[max_idx])
#S:1
```

**Update**
For a faster approach, I have sorted the inner list of all the dictionaries in place on the key `ce_fraction`, and the first element of your resultant list will be your answer

```
sorted_list = (sorted(d1[0], key = lambda i: i['ce_fraction'],reverse=True) )
print(sorted_list[0]['ce_symbol'])
#S:1
```

Comment: Thanks, Devesh. I was missing the logic "max_idx = ce_frac.index(max_frac)" before. I can get the result for this one. I was worried about the computing time because I have many such sets of lists to evaluate. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check my updated answer and if it helps you, please upvote and accept

Comment: Thanks. Got this error on the basis of your update:     sorted_list = (sorted(d1[0], key = lambda i: i['ce_fraction'],reverse=True) )

TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: I used your full list for the last part!

Answer (score 0):

```
from operator import itemgetter

d1 = [{'ce_symbol': 'S:1',
'ce_fraction': 0.9826993502161626,
'csm': 0.0,
'permutation': [0]},
{'ce_symbol': 'ST:7',
'ce_fraction': 0.01729545180302663,
'csm': 6.419666329644907,
'permutation': [3, 1, 4, 6, 0, 5, 2]},
{'ce_symbol': 'TL:3',
'ce_fraction': 5.112772362143661e-06,
'csm': 5.01422215914756,
'permutation': [0, 1, 2]},
{'ce_symbol': 'TS:3',
'ce_fraction': 6.631085890198608e-08,
'csm': 7.49194295399119,
'permutation': [0, 2, 1]},
{'ce_symbol': 'TY:3',
'ce_fraction': 1.8897589832589626e-08,
'csm': 7.720504649029379,
'permutation': [0, 1, 2]}]

lis = [(i["ce_fraction"],i["ce_symbol"]) for i in d1]
max_ce_symbol = min(lis,key=itemgetter(1))[1]

print(max_ce_symbol)
```

**Output**

```
'S:1'
```

Comment: If you check the value of the key you returned thats too small, in order of -08.

Comment: Apologies, missed it somehow